# Find the nth term of the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a series

$$\frac{x}{2},\frac{x}{4},\frac{3x}{4},\frac{x}{8},\frac{3x}{8},\frac{5x}{8},\frac{7x}{8},\frac{x}{16},\frac{3x}{16},\frac{5x}{16},\frac{7x}{16},\frac{9x}{16},\frac{11x}{16},\frac{13x}{16},\frac{15x}{16}, \frac{x}{32},\cdots$$

Here $x$ can be any integer

What is the formula for the nth term of the series ?

Comment: Welcome to the math SE. You might want to format your series with MathJax or improve the spacing to make your question a bit more readable.

Comment: Please help me @Maroon how can i edit this question to make it more readable

Comment: There should be an edit link below your question next to the "share" link.

Comment: I should mention that the LaTeX code `\frac{a}{b}` gives $\frac ab$. (`\dfrac{a}{b}` makes it bigger in-line, like $\dfrac ab$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general formula for this series is:

$$a_n=x \cdot \frac{2n+1-2^{\lfloor \log(n) \rfloor+1}}{2^{\lfloor \log(n) \rfloor+1}}$$

it's when $a_1=x/2$.

Comment: thats it ...........@agha thank you so much ...

Comment: By $\log(n)$ do you mean the [binary logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm), $\log_2(n)$?

Comment: Yes, it's binary logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Look at the numerators. They all seem to be ascending odd numbers with an increasing period. Also, look at the corresponding denominators. They all seem to be powers of $2$.